# Mysql Connector and Entity Data Model Generator

Tags: .net, ado.net, mysql-connector

Im trying to get Entity Data Model with wizard from remote mysql server. I'm typing proper
connection string, then choose next. I see all tables, i can check them. When wizard finished im getting no entity models and this errors:

```
Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
    Access denied for user 'myserver'@'myIP' (using password: NO)
```

It's really strange, because with this same connection string i can acces database from server explorer. I include all needed refferences. I really can't figure out what is wrong here.

My connection string:

```
<add name="WebformSubmittedDataContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/WebformSubmittedData.csdl|res://*/WebformSubmittedData.ssdl|res://*/WebformSubmittedData.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=myserver;User Id=user;password=mypassword;database=base_name;port=3307&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Update 1:

I'v just tried connect manualy via code using Mysql Connector and it end with succesfull (grabbed specific data and display on console).

Answer (score 2):

Edit the connection to the `MySql Database Data Connection` in `Server Explorer` by right-clicking on the `MySQL Data Connection` and selecting `Modify Connection...`.

Make sure that `Save my password` is checked. If it is not checked, the connection attempt is made without a password even though the password is shown in the connection string in the `web.config` or `app.config` file.